# How to efficiently read part of raster data intersecting with vector data in R?

Tags: r, vector, raster

Given a large raster dataset (`ras`) (ideally Cloud optimized GeoTIFF) in projection A and a vector dataset (`vec`) in projection B covering a small part of `ras`. What is an efficient way to get the raster data intersecting with `vec` in R?

One way would be to read the data, reproject it, crop it, mask it.

```r
ras <- terra::rast(rasterpath)
vec <- sf::st_read(vectorpath)

ras_reproject <- terra::project(ras, terra::crs(vec))
ras_crop <- terra::crop(ras_reproject , vec)
```

But reprojection takes forever and I do not want to load the entire raster dataset in Memory.

Is there package with a function like `read_raster(rasterpath, extent=vec)`?

Comment: Have your tried setting the `xmin`, `xmax` ... , or the `extent` argument? According to the docs: *When a SpatRaster is created from a file, it does not load the cell (pixel) values into memory (RAM). It only reads the parameters that describe the geometry of the SpatRaster, such as the number of rows and columns and the coordinate reference system. The actual values will be read when needed.* (see `?rast`)

Comment: `xmin` etc. are not allowed when reading a raster from source. Initially it does not load the raster in memory, however I guess for projection the values are needed and read in memory

Comment: I see. Would setting the `mask`, and enabling `threads` in `terra::project` improve performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this works out in all situations yet,
but the {{ezwarp}} library and the underlying {{vapour}} library which builds on gdal kind of did what I wanted

```r
library(ezwarp)

ras_crop <- ezwarp(
  x = rasterpath, y = rasterpath, res = 10, cutline = vec,
  crop_to_cutline = TRUE, engine = "vapour"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could project the vector data, instead of the raster data. That would be much faster, but it is also generally better as it does not lead to data loss.

```
ras <- terra::rast(rasterpath)
vec <- terra::vect(vectorpath)

pvec <- terra::project(vec, ras)
ras_crop <- terra::crop(ras, pvec)
```